# How to try different function, and return first output that succeds in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, function

I have a couple of different functions, that each outputs a `json` string if successful. I cannot know beforehand whether they will fail or not so I want have to try them all in the order specified below. How can I do this?

I have tried things like:

```
import func1
import func2
import func3

def compi(url):
    try:
        return func1(url)
    except:
        return func2(url)
    else:
        return func3(url)
```

I am certain that `func3` will not fail.

Comment: are we talking about the function *returning something or not* **or** *throwing an error* **or** *both*? These are two very different things!

Comment: By returning nothing, i mean throwing an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def compi(url):
    functions = [func1, func2, func3]
    for func in functions:
        try:
            return func(url)
        except:
            pass
    #oops, none of them succeeded.
    raise Exception("All functions failed to return a value.")
```

Comment: *"to see if they return anything or not"* not sure what the OP's goal is. they might not raise an Error but return nothing

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Agreed, the OP's description is not perfectly clear. I wrote this answer under the assumption that `None` counts as something, in which case the only time a function does not return something is when it raises an uncaught exception.

Comment: @Kevin Works! Thx. Will accept, as soon as SO allows me.

Comment: @briyan The concept of SO is to help others while helping yourself so please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

Python functions are first-class objects, so instead of going through them manually, you can just make a list of them and loop through it, like so:

```
tested_funcs = [f1, f2, f3]
for f in tested_funcs:
    result = f(someinput)
    if result: break
return result
```

Wrap the inner block in a try/catch if it throws an error upon failing.